# How to measure Clock frequency of PIC?

Tags: clock, oscilloscope, clock-speed

I am using PIC micro controller (PIC16F1846) with an external 8MHz crystal attached to the external clock pins (RA6 and RA7).

Why is it that when I use my oscilloscope probe to attempt to measure the clock frequency my basic LED flashing program stops working (light state freezes) and I have to perform a reset?

Comment: Do you connect your oscilloscope to RA6 and RA7 at the same time ? I mean, probe tip to one and ground to the other ? Do you use a proper 1:10 probe ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a 10x (not 1x) probe on the OSC2 pin. You should be able to see the clock. The frequency will be slightly changed by the probe loading.

I don't think your part number is correct, but most 16F chips are similar.

Edit: Scope probe loading is explained in [this](http://www.tek.com/dl/51W_30013_0_MR_Letter_0.pdf) Tektronix paper.

Crystal pullability is explained in [this](http://www.ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/quar_des.pdf) application note. Note that the typical loading from a 10x scope probe would only change the frequency by perhaps 100ppm (0.01%), which is unimportant in many applications other than timekeeping.

Comment: Your correct, the part is actually PIC16F1847. Using the probe in x10 worked!

Comment: Could you explain this idea of the probe loading affecting the frequency?

Comment: Please see edit above

Comment: pdf link isn't working for me.

Comment: @DanNeely Should be working now. Tek appended some stuff to the URL that maybe was intended to discourage deep linking.

Comment: @hobbs  My Tek TPS2024 with P2220 probe is 200MHz BW on 10x and only 6MHz BW on 1x. The only reason to use 1x is low-level signals.

Answer (score 9):

This is a separate but related topic.

Measuring the frequency at the oscillator out pin tells you the oscillator frequency, not necessarily the instruction clock frequency.  On old PICs, that was just 1/4 of the oscillator frequency.  However, many newer PICs have more complicated clock chains than that, with a PLL and various optional dividers.

It is a good idea to make sure the instruction clock is actually what you think it is as early as possible.  I usually do this by having my main loop initially just toggle a pin.  Set up the bank for the appropriate LAT register first, then BSF, BCF, and BRA back to do it again.  That should take 4 instruction cycles.  You look at that on a scope and verify the pin frequency is really 1/4 of the instruction clock that you expected.

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer my question it is a very good point and probably has saved me a lot of pain down the line. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Capacity of the probe could cause failure of the clock generation. The simpliest way to prevent this is to wire a resistor to the central contact of the probe and perform the measurement placing another leg of the resistor onto your crystal. 100 Ohms will be fine.